# Finding the solutions using pyomo and gurobi

Tags: pyomo, gurobi

I have a code that uses pyomo and gurobi but when i try to run it, it doesn't give me the optimal solutions, just says that they exist. What can i do?

I have this:

```
TransformationFactory('gdp.bigm').apply_to(model)
opt = SolverFactory("gurobi", solver_io="python") 
opt.options['NonConvex'] = 2
opt.solve(model).write()
```

And it gives me this:

```
# ==========================================================
# = Solver Results                                         =
# ==========================================================
# ----------------------------------------------------------
#   Problem Information
# ----------------------------------------------------------
Problem:
- Name: unknown
  Lower bound: 3722.006655208413
  Upper bound: 3722.0163664746015
  Number of objectives: 1
  Number of constraints: 98859
  Number of variables: 57239
  Number of binary variables: 13996
  Number of integer variables: 13996
  Number of continuous variables: 29247
  Number of nonzeros: 200378
  Number of solutions: 10
# ----------------------------------------------------------
#   Solver Information
# ----------------------------------------------------------
Solver:
- Name: Gurobi 9.52
  Status: ok
  Wallclock time: 56.91826629638672
  Termination condition: optimal
  Termination message: Model was solved to optimality (subject to tolerances), and an optimal solution is available.
 ----------------------------------------------------------
   Solution Information
 ----------------------------------------------------------
Solution:
- number of solutions: 0
  number of solutions displayed: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

When `pyomo` receives the solution from the solver, it retains the optimal values loaded in all of the variables.  So, you have many options.

If you want to see the whole model, you can us `display` which substitutes in values:

```
model.display()
```

or for just one variable

```
model.x.display()
```

or you can query results of objects, like your objective function

```
value(model.obj)   # assumes your objective function is named obj
```

Here `value` is a `pyomo` function, so if you import and rename (which is recommended) like:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
```

Then it would be

```
pyo.value(model.obj)
```